# `const int* const int` initialisation with function

Tags: c++03

I want to define a constant array of constants at every MPI node using C++03. `M_chunk_sizes` defines the size of matrix that will be passed to other nodes and won't be changed during the runtime.

```
int* define_chunk_sizes( int S, int world) {

    int out[world];

    double quotient = static_cast<double> (S) / world;
    int maj = ceil(quotient);

    for (int i =0; i < world - 1; i++)
      out[i] = maj;

    out[world-1] = maj + (S - maj*world);

    return out;
}

int main() {
    const int M = 999; // rows
    int world_size = 4;
    const int* const M_chunk_sizes = define_chunk_sizes(M, world_size);
}
```

But i get a `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'out' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return out;`.

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

funciton local variables(stack varibales) will go out of scope and life once function returns.
you have use dynamic memory management operators, so allocate memory to  `out` using

`new`

and relase memory using

`delete`

once you done with it.

Comment: but i can `printf` my `M_chunk_sizes` after the last line of my code. Looks like it copies the result?

Comment: that behavior can't be guaranteed, it would seem like working but it will not work all the time. when function call returns all local variables on the stack will go out of scope, later  same space can be given to  stack frame of other program or some other function call, until its reuse it would look like working.  check this  `https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html` would help you to clear things and more understand of  it.

Comment: but if i do `new` for `M_chunk_sizes`, then i wont be able to initialise its values because it is constants pointer to constant ints. Am i able to do this without `constexpr`?

Comment: @93a   but You could do `new ` to `out` like `out =new int[world];` and initialize it and  `return out`, will that  not work ?

Comment: If i do `out = new int[world]` and `return out`, the warning still appears. I can suppress it by `return &(*out)`. Both of methods seems correct to me, because i set my new pointer to memory that i don't free, and hence, i don't care that variable `out` disappears from stack when function returns control.

Comment: @93a: good,  yes both  `out` and `&(*out)` are same address, both should work without any warning as per my undestanding